# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left( \cfrac{2x^2-1}{2x^2+3} \right)^{4x^2+2}$

Tags: limits

> I'm stuck in evaluating the following limit. $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\cfrac{2x^2-1}{2x^2+3}\right)^{4x^2+2} $$

This is what I've tried yet.

Let : $2x^2 + 1 = g(x)$ ; Then we've : $2x^2 - 1 = g(x) - 2 $ and $2x^2 + 3 = g(x) + 2 $

Therefore, the limit given can be written as: $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left( \cfrac{g(x)-2}{g(x) + 2} \right)^{2g(x)}$$

Now, as $x \to \infty$ then $g(x) \to \infty$ .

Therefore, we've: $$\lim_{g(x) \to \infty} \left(\cfrac{g(x) - 2}{g(x)+2} \right)^{2g(x)} $$

Although, I know that this idea seems to be really dumb as far as proper technique for this individual question is concerned. But, I can't think of any other technique right now.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try taking the logarithm of the thing and applying L'Hopital's rule. It might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $$A= \left(\cfrac{g - 2}{g+2} \right)^{2g}$$ and take logarithms $$\log(A)=2g\log\left(\cfrac{g - 2}{g+2} \right)=2g\log\left(\cfrac{1 -\frac 2 g}{1 +\frac 2 g} \right)=2g\Big( \log(1 -\frac 2 g)-\log(1 +\frac 2 g)\Big)$$ Now, use the development of $\log(1+x)$ when $x$ is small and replace successively $x$ by $ -\frac 2 g$ and $-\frac 2 g$.

After simplification, you should get $$\log(A)=-8-\frac{32}{3 g^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{g}\right)^4\right)$$ and then $$A=\frac{1}{e^8}-\frac{32}{3 e^8 g^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{g}\right)^4\right)$$ which reveals not only the limit but also how it is approached.

Comment: Can you link me to a source where I can see the development of log(1+x) when x is small? Is it about expansion of logarithmic series?

Comment: I supposed you knew it. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Comment: Gotcha! Sorry, I had got wrong with that sense due to Hunger! :D Thanks again, Mr. Claude. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You are very welcome !

Comment: am a bit confused with the last step. How did you get to that equation? :/

Comment: The reverse process $A=e^{\log(A)}$ and Taylor again if you want.

Comment: Ouch! Taylor hurts. I need to get it strong now. Thanks again, Mr. Claude.

Comment: I must confess that I am in love with Taylor ... series for almost sixty years ! It is extremely powerful.

Comment: Woohoo! I've been studying it too, for Basel Problem and Euler's Solution to it. It's awesome. I hope that I follow your doorsteps and become Maths enthusiast at an expressible level. Thanks again, SIr!

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite it as
$$
\left(1-\frac{4}{2x^2+3}\right)^{2(2x^2+3)-4}
$$
Call $n=2x^2+3$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{4}{n}\right)^{2n-4}=e^{-8}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me out. But, am confused how you got final value : $e^{-8}$ ?

Comment: You're welcome :) Anyway $(1-4/n)^n \to e^{-4}$. Therefore $(1-4/n)^{2n} \to e^{-8}$.. Constants "do not count" xd

Comment: Okay, so, it is more like : $(1-f(x))^{1/f(x)} \to e^{-1} $ ?

Comment: If $f(x) \to 0$ as $x\to \infty$, yes

Comment: Rightly pointed Captain! :D Thanks a lot Sir ;) :)

Comment: Try always to avoid De L'Hopitail whenever possible :P

Comment: Roger that! :D ..!

Answer (score 1):

Taking log $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log\left(\frac{2x^{2}-1}{2x^{2}+3}\right)}{1/\left(4x^{2}+2\right)}
 $$ and using L'Hopital's rule, we get $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}-\frac{8\left(2x^{2}+1\right)^{2}}{\left(2x^{2}-1\right)\left(2x^{2}+3\right)}=-8
 $$ hence $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{2x^{2}-1}{2x^{2}+3}\right)^{4x^{2}+2}=e^{-8}.
 $$

Comment: Can you explain how you got the first expression? Please!

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali I added a step.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Marco for your kind help. Glad you spared time to help me out. Regards!

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali You're welcome ;)