# finiding a limit base on the limit of $e$

Tags: limits

How can i find: $\lim_{x\to -\infty} \left(\cfrac{2x^3+5}{2x^3+3}\right)^{3x^3+5}$

I know that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\cfrac{x+1}{x}\right)^{x}=e$ but can't see how it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\left(1+\frac{2}{2x^3+3}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}(2x^3+3)}\cdot \left(1+\frac{2}{2x^3+3}\right)^{-\frac{5}{2}}  \to e^{2\cdot \frac{3}{2}} \cdot 1=e^3.
$$

Comment: can you elaborate? also x is approx to minus infinity.

Comment: x can approach $\pm \infty$, the result does not change.. What's unclear?

Comment: how you got to $e^2$ and also why $-2.5$ isn't in the solution.

Comment: The constants in the exponent do not count :) Look this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255612/evaluate-lim-x-to-infty-left-cfrac2x2-12x23-right4x22/1255620#1255620 it is similar and more detailed

Comment: well you just said there that it doesn't count but i can see why.

Comment: I edited the answer: the reason is that $\lim_n a_nb_n=\lim_n a_n \lim_n b_n$ :)

Comment: got it, thanks!

Comment: Right, fixed __

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Start with $$A= \left(\cfrac{2x^3+5}{2x^3+3}\right)^{3x^3+5}$$ and take logarithms $$\log(A)=(3x^3+5)\log\left(\cfrac{2x^3+5}{2x^3+3}\right)=(3x^3+5)\log\left(\cfrac{1+\frac 5{2x^3 }}{1+\frac 3 {2x^3}}\right)$$ $$\log(A)=(3x^3+5)\Big(\log(1+\frac 5{2x^3 })-\log(1+\frac 3{2x^3 })\Big)$$ Now, use the development of $\log(1+y)$ when $y$ is small and make $y=\frac 5{2x^3 }$ in the first term and $y=\frac 3{2x^3 }$ in the second term.

This can show you not only the limit but also how it is approached.

I am sure that you can take from here.